# Open a fullscreen modal only in a div

Tags: html, css, menu, overlay

I'm using this 
    http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_fullscreen_overlay.asp

and I have two divs, one above the other. I would like to know how to open my fullscreen overlay only in a div and note in fullscreen thank you

At the beginning I wanted to use top:50%, but the height of my first div is not fixed,

Comment: show us the code you tried?

Comment: I just tried to add top:50% to the class .overlay, but when my div content is more than 50%, my modal is on it. I just wanted to know if in my link when you click on slide right or down, you can open the modal in a div ?

Answer (score 0):

If you change position:fixed inside the overlay class to position:absolute and give it a width, will that work for you?

I'm using the below page and changing the overlay class:
http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_overlay2

```
.overlay {
    height: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

Comment: This is what I've done when my two divs were at left and right, but when they are above, can I play with the height ? I want to open my modal in function of the height of my first div.